# How to automatically visit a website in the background after Ubuntu booted?

Tags: crontab, scheduled, w3m

I wanted to know how to automatically visit a website in the background when Ubuntu loads. As far as I know `w3m` is for visiting web site from the console. That is why I am writing following command in the `crontab -e`.

```
@reboot w3m http://example.com/ > test_file
```

The reason for writing content of the web site into a `test_file` is just to know whether this command has been executed or no.  Unfortunately it is not executing every time Ubuntu loads. But next command which comes after it and looks like this: `@reboot date >> reboot_file` is being executed every time.

What is wrong with my command? When I execute it in the console it outputs the content of the `example.com` into `test_file`.

Is there any other options to do that?

Comment: Just a long shot, but does `test_file` exist already? What are the permissions on it if it does?

Comment: Where are you checking for `test_file`? It might help to use a full path such as `/home/user/test_file`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use absolute paths where possible. It's possible that `PATH=/bin`, which works for `date` (=> `/bin/date`), but not for `w3m` (which is located at `/usr/bin/w3m`).

```
@reboot /usr/bin/w3m http://example.com/ > test_file
```

For further troubleshooting, look at `/var/log/syslog`; cron writes all executed commands to there.

Example of failed command:

```
Feb 28 13:27:01 ubuntu CRON[23705]: (username) CMD (/failing/command)
Feb 28 13:27:01 ubuntu CRON[23704]: (CRON) error (grandchild #23705 failed with exit status 127)
Feb 28 13:27:01 ubuntu CRON[23704]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

Answer (score 3):

How about catching the error messages in that file too:

```
@reboot w3m http://example.com/ > test_file 2>&1
```